# X on right side of div

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

So, I am building a menu of sorts. What it should be is each item name should be in the middle of the div, but the XIcon needs to be on the right side (for closing the item/div). Here is the code

```
<div class="hidden sm:block">
      <div class="border-b border-gray-200">
        <nav class="-mb-px flex justify-between" aria-label="Tabs"> 
          <a v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.name" :href="tab.href" :class="[tab.current ? 'border-indigo-500 text-indigo-600' : 'border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-200', 'w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 font-medium text-sm']" :aria-current="tab.current ? 'page' : undefined">
            {{ tab.name }}             <XIcon class="h-6 w-6 text-black" aria-hidden="true" />
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I just don't know what the best way to accomplish this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `float-right` to the XIcon div fixed it